# mysql db heavy load and numerous connection

Tags: mysql, caching

In my work I need to revamp the web which need to accept numerous connection always. Before I use the JSON to get the data until now.But now I want to direct call the DB and get the data. As I know use cache is the best way for my web. But in initial the concurrent access to DB is often happen.Any advice for me to handle the situation. Because I want the web that can get the updated data always.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following are my suggestions

1. If you want to use cache, you have to automate your cache clear process whenever there is an update in the particular data you hit. But this is practically possible if your data is updated **infrequently**.
2. If your budget allows, Put your DB in a cluster (Write in master and read from master&slave)
3. In worst case,ensure your db is properly indexed.